# Why do vertex labels disappear when I edit with drawing tools?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to change the text and arrow style in GraphPlot using the drawing tool, but the the vertex labels disappear when I do that:

```
GraphPlot[{Subscript[δ, 1] -> Subscript[X, 1], 
  Subscript[δ, 2] -> Subscript[X, 2], 
  Subscript[δ, 3] -> Subscript[X, 3], 
  Subscript[δ, 4] -> Subscript[X, 4], 
  Subscript[ξ, 1] -> 
   Subscript[ξ, 2], {Subscript[ξ, 2] -> Subscript[ξ, 1], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(21\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     1] -> Subscript[X, 1], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(11\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     1] -> Subscript[X, 2], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(21\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     2] -> Subscript[X, 3], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(32\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     2] -> Subscript[X, 4], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(42\)]\)"}}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> {Subscript[ξ, 1] -> {0, 3}, 
   Subscript[ξ, 2] -> {0, 0}, Subscript[X, 3] -> {Sqrt[3], 1}, 
   Subscript[X, 4] -> {Sqrt[3], -1}, Subscript[X, 2] -> {Sqrt[3], 2}, 
   Subscript[X, 1] -> {Sqrt[3], 4}, 
   Subscript[δ, 1] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, 4}, 
   Subscript[δ, 2] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, 2}, 
   Subscript[δ, 3] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, 1}, 
   Subscript[δ, 4] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, -1}}, ImageSize -> 320]
```

results something like

[image]

when I use the drawing tool to make the text and arrow head bigger, the vertex labels disappear

[image]

Why that happens and how to get around that? I'm using version 8 on Mac. This also happens in version 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: On version 9 (Mac) you can change the size of the labels freely (and they're still visible), but as soon as I touch the Arrowhead sliders they disappear and don't come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a problem of the interactive drawing interface, it may be OK to work around it in an interactive way, too. It's a hack, of course, but don't blame me.

Here is a sequence of steps that works. It's based on point-and-click interaction, so I can best describe it visually in steps. For that reason, I made the `ImageSize` in the original graph smaller:

```
GraphPlot[{Subscript[δ, 1] -> Subscript[X, 1], 
  Subscript[δ, 2] -> Subscript[X, 2], 
  Subscript[δ, 3] -> Subscript[X, 3], 
  Subscript[δ, 4] -> Subscript[X, 4], 
  Subscript[ξ, 1] -> 
   Subscript[ξ, 2], {Subscript[ξ, 2] -> Subscript[ξ, 1], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(21\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     1] -> Subscript[X, 1], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(11\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     1] -> Subscript[X, 2], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(21\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     2] -> Subscript[X, 3], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(32\)]\)"}, {Subscript[ξ, 
     2] -> Subscript[X, 4], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(γ\), \(42\)]\)"}}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> {Subscript[ξ, 1] -> {0, 3}, 
   Subscript[ξ, 2] -> {0, 0}, Subscript[X, 3] -> {Sqrt[3], 1}, 
   Subscript[X, 4] -> {Sqrt[3], -1}, Subscript[X, 2] -> {Sqrt[3], 2}, 
   Subscript[X, 1] -> {Sqrt[3], 4}, 
   Subscript[δ, 1] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, 4}, 
   Subscript[δ, 2] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, 2}, 
   Subscript[δ, 3] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, 1}, 
   Subscript[δ, 4] -> {Sqrt[3] + 1, -1}}, ImageSize -> 120]
```

Now **copy** the output into a new line, pasting it **twice** into a `Show` statement as follows:

[image: step1]

**Don't evaluate** the cell yet. First invoke the graphics editor and modify the left-hand plot by changing the arrow heads in the right-hand plot to your liking.

[image: step2]

**Still don't evaluate** the cell yet. Change the `Opacity` of the edges in the right-hand plot until they are invisible:

[image: step 3]

**Then** evaluate the `Show`:

[image: result]

So I superimposed two copies, one with the right arrows but no labels, and one with no labels but the right arrows. The latter has to be drawn first so that the labels are shown on top.

Comment: That works! Thanks!